# Parsing a short string from html source

Tags: c#

```
<br />
Your coupon for 50% off MSRP - Inline is: XXXXXXXXXXX<br />
Your coupon for 50% off MSRP - Outdoor is: XXXXXXXXXXX<br /><br />
```

I wish to parse out the coupon code. 
I current have `is(.+?)<br>` but its also including the `<br>` at the end.

Comment: are the coupon codes all the same length?

Comment: no they are not. They vary in length.

Comment: a [relevant answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1):

Try a lookbehind/lookahead pattern like this:

```
".*?coupon.*?(?<=: )(\\w+)(?=<br />|<br/>)"
```

It matches alphanumeric data, into capture group 1, that has the word `"coupon"` and is between the `": "` and `"<br />"` or `<br/>"`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string html = "<br />\n" +
            "Your coupon for 50% off MSRP - Inline is: XXXXXXXXXXX<br />" +
            "Your coupon for 50% off MSRP - Outdoor is: XXXXXXXXXXX<br /><br />";

        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, ".*?coupon.*?(?<=: )(\\w+)(?=<br />|<br/>)");
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
XXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXX
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mrc6oi)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without even using Regex.  Something like

```
string s = "Your coupon for 50% off MSRP - Outdoor is: XXXXXXXXXXX";
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
```

should work as long as the coupon code is always the last part of the string, with a space prefixing it.

EDIT: one alternative after seeing your edit and that the strings are wrapped in `<br>`, you could always .Replace the match results with an empty string-

```
string s = "Your coupon for 50% off MSRP - Outdoor is: XXXXXXXXXXX<br>";
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1).Replace("<br>",""));
```

Comment: I'm trying to parse from a html page though.